# NOT_FOUND_ERR when appending to table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, html-table

I did find several questions concerning the `NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8` error in combination with jQuery, but they did not happen in a scenario like mine and as such they did not provide a solution.

Basically, I have an object and I'm iterating over it and then adding rows to a `<table>` with `id="legend"`: http://jsfiddle.net/nt9gZ/.

```
var items  = [],
    obj    = {a: 1,
              b: 2};

$.each(obj, function(i, v) {
    items.push(
        $("<tr>").append(
            $("<td>").html(i),
            $("<td>").html(v)
        )
    );
});

// .empty() is to erase contents when running this piece of code again
$("#legend").empty().append(
                        $(items)
                     );
```

When I run this piece of code, I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

on Chrome.

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with my code.

- What cannot be found?
- How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/nt9gZ/8/

Basically there problem with the array - `append` method does not take array of jQuery objects as an argument, only a sequence of elements. So I've used `add` method to collect all rows together.

Comment: Thanks. Just for the record I created a simple function that does a sort of `.add` on the current set of elements. http://jsfiddle.net/nt9gZ/10/

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to insert an array of arrays..

Add a `.get(0)` when you are pushing the created object in the array, so that you insert the actual DOM fragments..

```
$.each(obj, function(i, v) {
    items.push(
        $("<tr>").append(
            $("<td>").html(i),
            $("<td>").html(v)
        ).get(0)
    );
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nt9gZ/7/

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your below code

```
$("<tr>").append(
            $("<td>").html(i),
            $("<td>").html(v)
        )
```

But here is another way to achieve the same.

```
var items  = [],
obj = {a: 1, b: 2};

$.each(obj, function(i, v) {
    items.push("<tr>"+"<td>"+i+"</td><td>" + v +"</td></tr>");
});

$("#legend").append(items.join(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

from your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt9gZ/5/)

Append do not expect array in the first argument.
However, reading the doc, the second arg can be an array. I can't manage to pass an array and make it work (as the second argument) though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt9gZ/9/)

you should loop over items in `items` array and append 'em one by one

Comment: I am assuming the OP want to avoid a per-item insertion to avoid reflows/repainting of the page. Instead doing it in one go, drop the reflow to a single time.

Comment: Thanks but this drops the `<tr>`s it seems.